# Error deploying node app to heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I'm relatively new to node, and have been having issues deploying a node web app to heroku... it seems to have to do with how I'm creating my mongoose connection in my server file. Here are the error logs I'm getting:

```
2016-01-06T00:41:30.384170+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-01-06T00:43:56.191644+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-01-06T00:43:57.774259+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server/server.js`
2016-01-06T00:44:00.138974+00:00 app[web.1]: listening on 4568
2016-01-06T00:44:00.172982+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-01-06T00:44:00.172992+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:236
2016-01-06T00:44:00.172994+00:00 app[web.1]:         process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
2016-01-06T00:44:00.172994+00:00 app[web.1]:                                       ^
2016-01-06T00:44:00.172995+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
2016-01-06T00:44:00.172996+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
2016-01-06T00:44:00.172997+00:00 app[web.1]:     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
2016-01-06T00:44:00.172998+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
2016-01-06T00:44:00.968046+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-01-06T00:44:00.983259+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

And here is a shell of my server file:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var entryController = require('./entries/entryController.js');

    var app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../client'));

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost');

    console.log('listening on 4568');
    app.listen(4568);
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to connect to localhost:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost');
```

Localhost means "this computer." Your database is not running in the same container on Heroku as your node app, so instead you need to connect to where your database really is hosted.

You may want to read a tutorial like:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-mongodb-with-a-node-application-on-heroku

Comment: All that link says is to use a MongoLab add-on config variable to set your db uri. Are you suggesting that you should push your db credentials somewhere?